# Composer install / update for Symfony failing with 302 errors

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, http-status-code-302

I have installed composer and downloaded a Symfony app from the git server and am having issues when doing a composer install or update (same issues). Here is the output from an update:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 38 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download psr/log from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/log/zipball/4ebe3a8bf773a19edfe0a84b6585ba3d401b724d" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Cloning 4ebe3a8bf7 from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.10): Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download paragonie/random_compat from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/paragonie/random_compat/zipball/634bae8e911eefa89c1abfbf1b66da679ac8f54d" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.10): Cloning 634bae8e91 from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.5.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v3.3.6): Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download symfony/symfony from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/symfony/zipball/6f80cbd2dd89c5308b14e03d806356fac72c263e" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v3.3.6): Cloning 6f80cbd2dd


  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]               
  The process "git clone --no-checkout 'https://github.com/symfony/symfony.gi  
  t' '/var/www/html/beyondrgtt/vendor/symfony/symfony' && cd '/var/www/html/b  
  eyondrgtt/vendor/symfony/symfony' && git remote add composer 'https://githu  
  b.com/symfony/symfony.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 3  
  00 seconds.
```

I have been trying for the past few hours, so this may be an issue with the github servers that will go away in time. Has anyone had this issue? I have tried --prefer-source as well, takes ages to install symfony/symfony and a few others and then shows:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not scan for classes inside "/var/www/html/projectname/vendor/symfony/  
  symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs" which does not appear t  
  o be a file nor a folder
```

Comment: I have the same problem here.

Comment: OK, so this could be a current github issue maybe? Is this an ongoing issue for you? When did it start happening?

Comment: Like an hour ago, but I havent use composer since 2 weeks maybe.

Comment: No worries, thanks for that, I'll leave it for now and see if its fixed tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah. I guess it wasn't the good time to get back into my [symfony project  ^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841958/symfony-composer-update-messes-with-symfonyrequirements-path)

Comment: May be back up I think.

Comment: I juste tried at home and composer seems working now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152688/discussion-between-micwit-and-chuck-norris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this issue was a temporary issue (I am guessing on github) where the resource was not available so it was trying to re-direct.

If this happens in the future, seems best bet is wait a few hours (in this case it was about 3 or 4 hours) to see if the problem resolves itself.