# Symfony composer update messes with SymfonyRequirements path

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I created a new Symfony project `symfony new test`.

Then if I check Symfony Requirements `php bin/symfony_requirements` , it works as expected.

**bin/symfony_requirements**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../var/SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

But when I made a `composer update`, in `bin/symfony_requirements` and in `web/config.php`, the path to SymfonyRequirements.php is changed to :

**bin/symfony_requirements** and **web/config/php**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/./SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

So obviously, calling `symfony_requirements` or `config.php` with the browser failed since the path to SymfonyRequirements is wrong.

This is the first time that composer messes like that.

I have the latest composer (1.5.1).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's a [reported issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6599) without solution yet. In the meantime, revert the changes in these files.

Comment: I did a lot of research but wasn't able to find any information on this. So thank you for the link :)